# Disk Image Mounter from Nautilus (Files) Context Menu Fails to Mount ISO

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, nautilus, iso

Ubuntu 20.04 attempting to mount ISO file using Disk Image Mounter from Nautilus (Files) Context Menu fails to mount ISO with the following message -

[image]

However going `mount somefile.iso /mnt` results in the same ISO file mounting without issue.

I would prefer to use Disk Image Mounter.  Any ideas how I can fix this problem?